# d3.js doughnut chart :: Additional paths are rendered and not updated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having problems rendering doughnut charts in d3.  I have 2 doughnuts, that I'm creating side-by-side inside of a for each function::

```
         data.forEach(function(d,i){...}
```

The charts render fine. When I go to update the chart, paths are redrawn.  Not sure why this happening because I'm using .enter()

Any advise?

```
        var singleDonutData = [1];

        var donutSections=singleDonut.selectAll(".donutSections")
            .data(singleDonutData)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class","donutSections");

        var pathGroup = svg.select("." + donutName).select(".donutSections").selectAll("path.arc")
            .data(pie(d));

        var path = pathGroup
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .style('fill', function(d){   //give arc a color in SVG Scale
                return color(d.data.label);
            })
            .attr("d", arc)
            .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial angles;
```

Comment: are you able to provide js fiddle or any working example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add corresponding class name on the generated path, for example:

```
var pathGroup = svg.select("." + donutName).select(".donutSections").selectAll("path.arc")
        .data(pie(d));

    var path = pathGroup
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .style('fill', function(d){  
            return color(d.data.label);
        })
        .attr("class", "arc") // corresponding to selectAll("path.arc")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); angles;
```

So that when you update the chart, d3 can correctly select these already rendered path.

After this update, you also need to add code to handle the update selection. Something like this:

```
pathGroup.transition().duration(1000)
.attrTween("d", function(d){
   // some transition animation code here if you need it.
})
```